# RISCV out of range

Tags: riscv

i am trying to learn RISCV assembly. I am trying to learn the ISA and implement some R type, S type instruction. However whenever i try to run the sw and lw instruction. It always gives me error address out of range and i don't understand why. This is an example:

```
lw  a0,40(zero)
addi    a1,zero,1
addi    a2,zero,1
beq a0,a1,SAVE
LOOP:
addi    a1,a1,1
addi    t1,a1,0
addi    t2,a2,0
jal ra,MUL
add a2,zero,t0
bne a1,a0,LOOP
SAVE:
sw  a2,44(zero)
jal x0,DONE
MUL:
andi    t0,t0,0
LOOP_MUL:
add t0,t0,t2
addi    t1,t1,-1
bne t1,zero,LOOP_MUL
jalr    zero,ra,0
DONE:
add zero,zero,zero
```

I get some error like this : Error in D:\ctmt\BTL_RISCV\riscv1.asm line 2: Runtime exception at 0x00400004: address out of range 0x00000004.
I am really grateful if someone can explain to me why this bug happens

Comment: What does this question have to do with verilog or VHDL? In any case, why are you using those hardcoded addresses like `40(zero)`? How do you know that that's in a region of memory that you're allowed to access?

Answer (score 1):

Address out of range applies to load and store instructions.  It tells you the address of the instruction (because that's what the hardware sees/knows), and the address you are attempting to access.  Usually such is because of a bad pointer value in the base register, but sometimes, the pointer value is close to the end of a something and the immediate value puts it past the end.

You should look at the memory map for the simulator or environment that you're using, it may tell you what areas of memory are legal — it may also support reconfiguring the memory map.  Low memory (values from 0-2048 or so) are not guaranteed to be legal memory locations on many systems, but can sometimes be configured as legal for small memory models, e.g. on embedded systems.  One reason low memory is configured as illegal is to catch null pointer dereferencing, which is a common software error (using a null pointer).